# How to find an element by partial href?

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

How can I locate that element with xpath? (class name is not unique).

`<a class="my-action" href="/my/path/page.html"></a>`

Tried:
`//a[@href='/my/path/page.html']` but did not succeed. What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `contains` like

```
//a[contains(@href, 'path/page.html')]
```

Append `.` to your XPath if necessary, which means start from current node, not globally.

```
.//a[contains(@href, 'path/page.html')]
```

For Selenium, it'd be better to use CSS Selector in your case.

```
a[href*='path/page.html']
```

However, you need provide more info on why your XPath doesn't work. Post exception message please. Maybe the issue isn't about partial href in XPath or not. Please avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 1):

`example = browser.find_element_by_class_name("my-action"[href*='my']")`

Comment: It's a good idea to add some explanation so users can make use of your answer more readily. code only answer sometimes wont serve the purpose for users and its difficult to understand -Review